# How to access service in activity from fragment as soon as it's ready?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a `FragmentActivity`, and I'm binding to a service in its `onResume` method. I also have a `Fragment` that gets added to the activity. The `Fragment` will call the service from the `doInBackground` method in an `AsyncTask` to do some initialization first, and then after the initialization, a button in the fragment will become enabled. But when I tried to execute the `AsyncTask` from the fragment's `onActivityCreated` or `onResume` method, I get a `NullPointerException` when trying to get the service.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void params) {
      return activity.getMyService().doSomeInit(); // getMyService() returns null
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      someButton.enabled(result);
    }

  }.execute();
}
```

The activity will connect to the service, but how can I tell the fragment that the service is ready to be used (and therefore no longer null)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are setting the variable `activity` to `getActivity()` from your fragment at some point. My  guess is that the fragment has not been attached when you do that and thus `activity` is null and not `getMyService()`